# MediaWiki raw api returning old version of page when called in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I'm writing a todo extension for MediaWiki. I have a textbox which takes in the item and appends it to the page by calling the API with the 'raw' action, inserting the new item's html/css into the returned raw page then replacing the page's wikitext with the updated version. If I visit the URL in my browser

```
http://url/wiki/index.php?title="+pagetoappend+"&action=raw
```

I get the correct raw wikitext of the current page. However when I call it in my JavaScript:

```
$.get("http://url/wiki/index.php?title="+pagetoappend+"&action=raw")
```

it returns an older version of the page which has no items appended to it yet. This means each time I run the script it deletes the previous item and replaces it rather than appending it to my list.

It doesn't seem to be a  problem with my JS as I'm printing the wikitext returned by the JS call to the API in the console and it is retrieving the 'old' version of the page. I've tried purging the page with no change in behaviour.

Is there a cache of returned API calls or something that I need to purge? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could this be some caching problem? Does your wiki use some kind of caching?

Comment: Good thought but disabling the cache makes no difference. Even tried disabling the cache completely then making a new page to test on to make sure there'd be nothing cached. Same result. So frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

So while I didn't figure out what I was doing wrong, I used the following instead:

```
$.get("http://url.com/wiki/api.php?page="+pagetoappend+"&action=parse&prop=wikitext&format=json")
```

Then parsed the JSON file for the wikitext

```
var data = jsondata.parse.wikitext["*"];
```

Problem not exactly solved, but avoided at least.

Answer (score 0):

Internal caches in MediaWiki tend to be invalidated at the appropriate time; most likely your browser caches the response. You can prevent that by appending a cache breaker parameter (or using the appropriate jQuery parameter which does that).

If you are appending to the end of the page (or a template), an easier approach is to use the `appendtext` parameter of the [edit API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=edit).

Comment: Ah, didn't consider a browser side caching. Never really considered that a jquery request would be beholden to those issues.
I originally was using appendtext but because I was inserting todo list items between pre-existing tags it wasn't appropriate.

Comment: Use `basetimestamp` then. "*each time I run the script it deletes the previous item and replaces it rather than appending it to my list*" is not something that should be possible to happen in a well-written API client.